# Как каждый раз прибавлять значение к нужному имени?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть БД. В которой записано:

```
nickname         kills
Misha            10
...              ...
```

При выполнение следующей команды, должно прибавлять к нику, который получаем через `killedby`, значение +1:

```
killedby = re.search(pkill, line).group(2)
    
DataBase = "...."
sqlite = sqlite3.connect(DataBase)
sqlite_cursor = sqlite.cursor()
    
sql = """UPDATE ServerKillers_1 SET kills = ? WHERE nickname = ?"""
sqlite.execute(sql, (str(killedby), #?#))
```

Как добавлять значение +1, когда выполняем код?

Comment: @MaxU, изменил, не то вставил..

Comment: А есть возможность вставлять или изменять (если есть такой ник), без проверок `if`?

Comment: Попробуйте так: UPDATE ServerKillers_1 SET kills = kills + 1 WHERE nickname = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
sql = """UPDATE ServerKillers_1 SET kills = kills + 1 WHERE nickname = ?"""

sqlite.execute(sql, (str(killedby), ))
```

Возможно вам будет интересно почитать об [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO ServerKillers_1 (nickname, kills) values(?, ?) 
ON CONFLICT(nickname) DO UPDATE SET kills = kills + 1
"""
```